# Double attack threshold (Path of Radiance)

Tags: fire-emblem-path-of-radiance

As commonplace in Fire Emblem Games, a unit in Path of Radiance attacks twice if the difference between its speed and the enemy's speed reaches a threshold. Fire Emblem Wiki states that this threshold is 4.

In Chapter 15, I have the following Marcia (speed = 22)

[image]

trying to attack Muarim (speed = 18).

[image]

Even though she reached the threshold (4), she won't attack twice. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

She won't attack twice because her weapon is heavy enough to slow down her Attack Speed.

Attack Speed is based on Speed, but whenever a character uses a weapon with a Weight larger than their Strength, their Attack Speed is lowered by the difference.

Laguz Lances have a Weight of 17, which exceeds your Marcia's Strength by 2. Therefore, although her Speed is 22, her Attack Speed while wielding one is 20.

Claws have a Weight of 1 so Muarim with his 23 Strength here is not slowed down at all from his weapon, but the -1 on his speed from the Demi Band leaves his Attack Speed at 17.

Neither Attack Speed exceeds the other by 4, so no double attack occurs on either side.

https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Attack_speed

Comment: Technically Muarim's Attack Speed is 17 due to the -1 to speed from the Demi Band, but still doesn't meet the double attack threshold :)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure whether the -1 was included in the visible 18 or it still needed subtracted. The question said 18 speed so I trusted that's how the display worked since I didn't remember. Thanks. :)